# msaccess.exe not closed on remote machine

Tags: batch-file, ms-access-2013

I try to find answer on this topic but still fail to resolve my question.

I use a batch file to call a simple macro which only write a log into an access table.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE" "G:\Work***.accdb" /X mymacro
```

following is the vba code:

```
Public Sub TestSession()
  On Error Resume Next
  Set curr_db = CurrentDb()
  'write log here
  Call curr_db.Close
  Call Application.Quit
End Sub
```

When it's run on my local desktop, it works well and the cmd is closed without any msaccess.exe in the task manager.
But when I copy this bat and modify the path(change g:\ to \servername) to a remote machine, the cmd is still opened with msaccess.exe in the task manager.
and both have written the log successfully.

The final purpose is to setup a schedule task to run the macro for a time.

more comment: 
I'd like to setup up a schedule task on a remote machine, and the remote machine has installed access too, the .accdb is on a network drive. the solution is use the schedule task to run a bat which will start access and open a macro in .accdb.(the bat and access is in remote machine, the .accdb is on network drive.)

I try a lot and can't solve it by myself, appreciate any help, thanks a lot.

Comment: any reason it has to be msaccess? Log files are usually done as text files where a string is appended to the end of hte log file.

Comment: this is code just to test the issue,not only to use access to write log.

Comment: Don't do `curr_db.Close`, only `Application.Quit`. But that's probably not the issue.

Comment: Do you want to run the batch on a remote machine, or do you run MSACCESS.EXE on your local machine with the .accdb on a network drive?

Comment: That is not a batch script.  It looks more like Basic.

Comment: attached code is in vba.

Comment: I'd like to setup up a schedule task on a remote machine, and the remote machine has installed access too, the .accdb is on a network drive. the solution is use the schedule task to run a bat which will start access and open a macro in .accdb.(the bat and access is in remote machine, the .accdb is on network drive.)